# Stop timer using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

Im using a function to start a count up timer using moment.js library , how could I make a stop timer function?

```
function startTimer()
{
var startTimestamp = moment().startOf("day");
setInterval(function() {
    startTimestamp.add(1, 'second');
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =  
    startTimestamp.format('HH:mm:ss'); }, 1000);
  }
  startTimer();

  <div id="timer"></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout / clearTimeout problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015319/settimeout-cleartimeout-problems)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function startTimer() {
        var startTimestamp = moment().startOf("day");
        var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            startTimestamp.add(1, 'second');
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
                startTimestamp.format('HH:mm:ss');
        }, 1000);
    }
    startTimer();

    function stopTimer() {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
```

1. Store your interval in a variable. I called it `myInterval`.
2. Create a new function called `stopTimer();` that uses the `clearInterval()` method to clear your interval.
3. Create your button or whatever DOM element to trigger this, and set the `onClick` to `stopTimer();`